# Add 120 volt outlet to a 240 volt disconnect

Tags: 120-240v

I have a 240 volt breaker in my main breaker panel feeding a local outdoor disconnect (black, white, red & ground) for an outdoor sauna. Can I take leads off the black, white & groun, before the disconnect and make a local 120 panel with its own breaker?

Comment: How many amps is this 240V breaker, how many amps does the sauna pull, and how big is the wire running to the sauna disconnect?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually want to do is install a **subpanel**. The subpanel can then include both 120V (e.g., 15A or 20A) breakers for receptacles or lighting and a 240V breaker for the original sauna use. The specifics will depend a bit on:

- Existing wire size
- Existing breaker size
- Requirements of the existing sauna circuit

Keep in mind that there are GFCI requirements (which can be handled in the subpanel or possibly in the main panel) and that ground & neutral should be kept separate in the subpanel. The subpanel could have a main breaker that is larger than the breaker in the main panel that is connected to the wire that goes to the subpanel.

Comment: If it's on the same building, it doesn't even need a main breaker of its own...